# Error: Could not get unknown property 'iosX64' for KotlinTargetPreset in Android Studio 3.1.4?

Tags: android, ios, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Hi I am new to Android and Kotlin environment, I am from native iOS background.

I want to create a Kotlin MultiPlatform app and it is run-on both Android and iOS.

For this I am following this 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html

After complete the **Updating Gradle Scripts** process from the above documentation I am facing issue like:

**Could not get unknown property 'iosX64' for KotlinTargetPreset container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.**

and my build.gradle file path is **/Kotlin_Practice/KTMPDemo/SharedCode/build.gradle**

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos") \
                              ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64
        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
        }
    }
}
// workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27170
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

Can I update / downgrade my Gradle ?? How can I fix this above issue? 
Thank you.

My system Configuration:

Mac mini (Late 2014), macOS High Sierra, v10.13.5.

Android Studio Android Studio 3.1.4

Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 24, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue just now and by lack of answers I continued my search. Getting the example project running on first try meant there must've something of on my setup.

In my case it was not having the 1.3 Kotlin Gradle plugin version.
You will have multiple .gradle files by now. Presumably your main-project one will have something like this:

`classpath
   "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

Make sure the kotlin-version points to a 1.3 one. I used the same as example project and I had a 1.2.71 before. Things started working for me after that. I'm sure there's much more hurdles to take, but this might get you a bit further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed to ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71' to  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3' in main build.gradle file. After I run my project its showing error like: 

Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.

Comment: At the time of writing I used 1.3.0-rc-57. I got this from their example app: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/blob/master/tutorials/mpp-iOS-Android/build.gradle (make sure you have a gradle kotlin plugin of 1.3 in your IDE as well)

Comment: Thank you and Sorry for lately reply to you, currently I am working on another project in python. Once I will check and update you.